# How to get a property of a all child node having same name pattern using xpath query?

Tags: xpath, aem

Below is the structure of nodes:-

```
etc
  |___commerce
             |___aib
                    |__products
                            |____ product1
                            |           |____prices
                            |                   |____price
                            |_____product2      |____price1 
                            |                   |____price2
                            |_____ ....         |____price3
                            |                   |____....
                            |                   |____....
                            |_____ ....
```

There is a "from" property of Date type on every price node i want to find out all the products who range from 2014-04-21 to 2015-04-21. for this i'm using below query

```
path=/etc/commerce/aib/products
type=nt:unstructured
nodename=price*
1_property=from
1_property.lowerBound=2014-04-21T00:00:00.000Z
1_property.lowerOperation=>=
1_property.upperBound=2015-04-21T00:00:00.000Z
1_property.upperOperation=<=
p.limit=-1
```

But i'm getting all the products . can you please check what's wrong with this query.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

The usage of the [daterange predicate](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/DateRangePredicateEvaluator.html) is wrong. You should try as shown below.

```
path=/etc/commerce/aib/products
type=nt:unstructured
nodename=price*
1_daterange.property=from
1_daterange.lowerBound=2014-04-21T00:00:00.000+01:00
1_daterange.upperBound=2015-04-21T00:00:00.000+01:00
```

Comment: CQ/AEM has some strange extensions to xpath, good catch on the daterange operators.